# Spring java based configuration with scope prototype in imported configurations

Tags: java, spring

Is it possible to have beans of imported java based configurations be created with prototype scope?

What I mean is that if I have the following example code:

```
ApplicationContext applicationContext = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(
        SpringTopLevelConfig.class);

for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
    System.out.println(applicationContext.getBean(Student.class));
}
```

Where

```
public class Notebook {
    static int idCounter = 1;
    private final int id;

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Notebook{" +
               "id=" + id +
               '}';
    }

    public Notebook() {
        id = idCounter++;
    }
}

public class Student {
    private final Notebook notebook;

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Student{" +
               "notebook=" + notebook +
               '}';
    }

    public Student(Notebook notebook) {
        this.notebook = notebook;
    }
}
```

And spring Config is :

```
@Configuration
public class SpringTopLevelConfig {

    @Scope(BeanDefinition.SCOPE_PROTOTYPE)
    @Bean
    Notebook notebook(){
        return new Notebook();
    }

    @Scope(BeanDefinition.SCOPE_PROTOTYPE)
    @Bean
    Student student(){
        return new Student(notebook());
    }
}
```

As expected each student gets its own notebook:

```
Student{notebook=Notebook{id=1}}
Student{notebook=Notebook{id=2}}
```

However if I try to split up the configuration across multiple classes all of the examples I have found suggest using `@Autowire` to accomplish this:

```
@Configuration
@Import(SpringConfigSecondLevel.class)
public class SpringTopLevelConfig {

    @Autowired
    Notebook notebook;

    @Scope(BeanDefinition.SCOPE_PROTOTYPE)
    @Bean
    Student student(){
        return new Student(notebook);
    }
}

@Configuration
public class SpringConfigSecondLevel {

    @Scope(BeanDefinition.SCOPE_PROTOTYPE)
    @Bean
    Notebook notebook(){
        return new Notebook();
    }
}
```

However now the students end up sharing one notebook which is not the behaviour I am trying to achieve.

```
Student{notebook=Notebook{id=1}}
Student{notebook=Notebook{id=1}}
```

Is there a spring way to achieve SCOPE_PROTOTYPE behaviour with split configuration classes or will I need to create a `NotebookFactory` bean to save the students from fighting each other over the same notebook?

Comment: You have to `Autowired` Notebook in Student class and remove final too

Comment: I would really prefer to steer away from property injection unless I am in a complete dead end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two config file approach did not have the expected result, because you autowire the notebook inside SpringTopLevelConfig class. That notebook instance will be created once, and used from all other student objects, since when you create the student, inside the student constructor you pass that notebook instance instead of the notebook() bean method. You can pass the notebook() bean method inside the student constructor by autowiring the whole config class, so that you can call it:

```
@Configuration
@Import(SpringConfigSecondLevel.class)
public class SpringTopLevelConfig {


    @Autowired SpringConfigSecondLevel springConfigSecondLevel;

    @Scope("prototype")
    @Bean
    Student student(){
        return new Student(springConfigSecondLevel.notebook());
    }
}

@Configuration
public class SpringConfigSecondLevel {

    @Scope("prototype")
    @Bean
    Notebook notebook(){
        return new Notebook();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since the Notebook instance is @Autowired it will be created once while creating the springTopLevelConfig singleton bean. This is evident from spring debug level logs

```
14:59:15.631 [main] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'springTopLevelConfig'
14:59:15.631 [main] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Creating instance of bean 'springTopLevelConfig'
14:59:15.639 [main] DEBUG o.s.b.f.annotation.InjectionMetadata - Registered injected element on class [com.example.spring.prototype_level.SpringTopLevelConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$2fffb2e0]: AutowiredFieldElement for com.example.spring.prototype_level.Notebook com.example.spring.prototype_level.SpringTopLevelConfig.notebook
14:59:15.640 [main] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Eagerly caching bean 'springTopLevelConfig' to allow for resolving potential circular references
14:59:15.673 [main] DEBUG o.s.b.f.annotation.InjectionMetadata - Processing injected method of bean 'springTopLevelConfig': AutowiredFieldElement for com.example.spring.prototype_level.Notebook com.example.spring.prototype_level.SpringTopLevelConfig.notebook
14:59:15.682 [main] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Creating instance of bean 'notebook'
14:59:15.682 [main] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'com.example.spring.prototype_level.SpringConfigSecondLevel'
14:59:15.682 [main] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Creating instance of bean 'com.example.spring.prototype_level.SpringConfigSecondLevel'
14:59:15.684 [main] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Eagerly caching bean 'com.example.spring.prototype_level.SpringConfigSecondLevel' to allow for resolving potential circular references
14:59:15.698 [main] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Finished creating instance of bean 'com.example.spring.prototype_level.SpringConfigSecondLevel'
14:59:15.731 [main] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Finished creating instance of bean 'notebook'
14:59:15.732 [main] DEBUG o.s.b.f.a.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor - Autowiring by type from bean name 'springTopLevelConfig' to bean named 'notebook'
14:59:15.733 [main] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Finished creating instance of bean 'springTopLevelConfig'
14:59:15.733 [main] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.importAwareProcessor'
14:59:15.733 [main] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.enhancedConfigurationProcessor'
14:59:15.733 [main] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'com.example.spring.prototype_level.SpringConfigSecondLevel'
14:59:15.736 [main] DEBUG o.s.c.a.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext - Unable to locate LifecycleProcessor with name 'lifecycleProcessor': using default [org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor@391663bd]
14:59:15.736 [main] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'lifecycleProcessor'
14:59:15.739 [main] DEBUG o.s.c.e.PropertySourcesPropertyResolver - Searching for key 'spring.liveBeansView.mbeanDomain' in [systemProperties]
14:59:15.739 [main] DEBUG o.s.c.e.PropertySourcesPropertyResolver - Searching for key 'spring.liveBeansView.mbeanDomain' in [systemEnvironment]
14:59:15.740 [main] DEBUG o.s.c.e.PropertySourcesPropertyResolver - Could not find key 'spring.liveBeansView.mbeanDomain' in any property source. Returning [null]
14:59:15.740 [main] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Creating instance of bean 'student'
14:59:15.740 [main] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'springTopLevelConfig'
14:59:15.752 [main] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Finished creating instance of bean 'student'
Student{notebook=Notebook{id=1}}
14:59:15.753 [main] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Creating instance of bean 'student'
14:59:15.753 [main] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'springTopLevelConfig'
14:59:15.753 [main] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Finished creating instance of bean 'student'
Student{notebook=Notebook{id=1}}
```

An alternative would be to inject the Notebook instance using applicationContext as below

```
@Configuration
@Import(SpringConfigSecondLevel.class)
public class SpringTopLevelConfig{

    @Autowired
    private ApplicationContext applicationContext;

    @Scope(BeanDefinition.SCOPE_PROTOTYPE)
    @Bean
    Student student(){
        return new Student(applicationContext.getBean(Notebook.class));
    }


}
```

Now spring will create the Notebook instance every time you create a Student instance. The spring logs too say so

```
14:55:51.255 [main] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'springTopLevelConfig'
14:55:51.255 [main] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Creating instance of bean 'springTopLevelConfig'
14:55:51.258 [main] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Eagerly caching bean 'springTopLevelConfig' to allow for resolving potential circular references
14:55:51.284 [main] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Finished creating instance of bean 'springTopLevelConfig'
14:55:51.285 [main] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.importAwareProcessor'
14:55:51.285 [main] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.enhancedConfigurationProcessor'
14:55:51.285 [main] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'com.example.spring.prototype_level.SpringConfigSecondLevel'
14:55:51.285 [main] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Creating instance of bean 'com.example.spring.prototype_level.SpringConfigSecondLevel'
14:55:51.287 [main] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Eagerly caching bean 'com.example.spring.prototype_level.SpringConfigSecondLevel' to allow for resolving potential circular references
14:55:51.292 [main] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Finished creating instance of bean 'com.example.spring.prototype_level.SpringConfigSecondLevel'
14:55:51.295 [main] DEBUG o.s.c.a.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext - Unable to locate LifecycleProcessor with name 'lifecycleProcessor': using default [org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor@1396a464]
14:55:51.297 [main] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'lifecycleProcessor'
14:55:51.300 [main] DEBUG o.s.c.e.PropertySourcesPropertyResolver - Searching for key 'spring.liveBeansView.mbeanDomain' in [systemProperties]
14:55:51.301 [main] DEBUG o.s.c.e.PropertySourcesPropertyResolver - Searching for key 'spring.liveBeansView.mbeanDomain' in [systemEnvironment]
14:55:51.302 [main] DEBUG o.s.c.e.PropertySourcesPropertyResolver - Could not find key 'spring.liveBeansView.mbeanDomain' in any property source. Returning [null]
14:55:51.302 [main] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Creating instance of bean 'student'
14:55:51.305 [main] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'springTopLevelConfig'
14:55:51.342 [main] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Creating instance of bean 'notebook'
14:55:51.342 [main] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'com.example.spring.prototype_level.SpringConfigSecondLevel'
14:55:51.352 [main] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Finished creating instance of bean 'notebook'
14:55:51.354 [main] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Finished creating instance of bean 'student'
Student{notebook=Notebook{id=1}}
14:55:51.355 [main] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Creating instance of bean 'student'
14:55:51.355 [main] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'springTopLevelConfig'
14:55:51.355 [main] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Creating instance of bean 'notebook'
14:55:51.355 [main] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'com.example.spring.prototype_level.SpringConfigSecondLevel'
14:55:51.355 [main] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Finished creating instance of bean 'notebook'
14:55:51.355 [main] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Finished creating instance of bean 'student'
Student{notebook=Notebook{id=2}}
```

Answer (score 1):

Others have explained why your first attempt did not work. I would only suggest a solution that does not require using an `@Autowired` field.

```
@Configuration
@Import(SpringConfigSecondLevel.class)
public class SpringTopLevelConfig {

    @Scope(BeanDefinition.SCOPE_PROTOTYPE)
    @Bean
    public Student student(Notebook notebook) {
        return new Student(notebook);
    }
}
```

If you simply add a method parameter of type `Notebook`, the Spring container will supply you with a new instance automatically.